# Is there something like JSON.stringify for xml?

Tags: javascript, xml

Is there something like JSON.stringify for xml. I want to convert an object in Javascript to a string formatted like an XML.

I want to basically convert a js object like this

```
{name: "Haynesville_Production", 
geometryType: "esriGeometryPoint", 
maxRecordCount: 1000}
```

to an xml string like this

```
<name>Haynesville_Production</name>
<geometryType>esriGeometryPoint</geometryType>
<maxRecordCount>1000</maxRecordCount>"
```

Comment: No, there isn't. You will need to search Google for a library.

Comment: It is not clear what input and expected result are?

Comment: [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)? [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer)? But no, you have to convert your "object" to a DOM tree first, manually - there is no standard translation.

Comment: I did, I cant find any. Hence the question? Do you know anything like that?

Comment: What are input and expected result? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

There is no native API for native object to XML serializing; however, there are 3rd party libraries such as this one which will output XML: http://code.google.com/p/x2js/

Answer (score -4):

You can iterate properties and values of a JavaScript object using `Object.entries()`, set the property name as opening and closing tag name of element, set node value to the value of the current iteration.

```js
let o = {
  name: "Haynesville_Production",
  geometryType: "esriGeometryPoint",
  maxRecordCount: 1000
}

let xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>`;

for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(o)) {
 xml += `<${key}>${prop}</${key}>`;
}

xml += "</root>";

console.log(xml);
```

Comment: Using a hand-built serializer like this is so easy, and so easy to get wrong: it's because so many people do this that we get so many questions on SO about how to handle bad XML. It's not that much harder to add the code to escape special characters like "<" and "&".

Comment: @MichaelKay Any pattern, "whether" simple or "complex", individuals and groups whom compose code  "get wrong" the code, else there would be no questions at SO at all. Whether the bug is considered simple or not does not matter. In that sense there is no distinction between "so easy" or not "so easy". The use of template literal negates need to escape special characters. The expected result is returned at Answer. If you propose a different solution post your Answer.  Who cares if there are "so many" questions on SO about anything. If the question does not interest you read a different question

Comment: @MichaelKay Or, if the subject matter does interest you, compose a detailed canonical Question/Answer to address the issue. Though note, that individuals are still free to determine their own procedure for resolving any inquiry.

Comment: That's a surprisingly defensive reaction. If you post code on StackOverflow and it contains errors then you should be pleased when they are pointed out because it will help you to avoid making the same mistakes in future. The fact that it's a very common mistake and that it causes so many people problems (when they have to handle ill-formed XML) makes it even more important for me to point it out.

Comment: @MichaelKay There are no errors at code at Answer that am aware of. The code creates a well-formed XML string capable of being loaded in a separate `window` as a `data URI`, or parsed as a `#document`.

Comment: What's the output if you change the "name" property to "Barnes & Noble"?

Comment: @MichaelKay An error is thrown. Would suggest changing property name to "BarnesAndNoble", that is, use camel case format with A-Za-z character set for property names. Note that OP does  use camel case A-Za-z format for property names of JavsScript plain object at code at Question.

Comment: I meant the value of the property, i.e. `name: "Barnes & Noble"`.

Comment: @MichaelKay An error occurs. Not sure what you are trying to convey? The world does not stop because there is a possible bug in your program.  If an error is thrown make appropriate adjustments and continue. By, for example, performing the necessary task at your suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638079/is-there-something-like-json-stringify-for-xml/45639168?noredirect=1#comment78241440_45639168 and using `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Comment: No, the world doesn't stop. It just wastes a lot of time.